# Why <h:outputScript> does not work inside <h:form>

Tags: forms, jsf, editor, tinymce, facelets

I am using JSF 2.1. I'm trying to use TinyEditor on a `<h:inputTextarea>`. Here is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>

    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="editor_style.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css/main.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css/dropdown.css" />    
    <h:outputScript name="js/tinyeditor.js"></h:outputScript>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div class="content">
        <ui:include src="/template/layout/commonLayout.xhtml" />
        <ui:include src="/template/layout/menu.xhtml" />
        <h:form>
            <div class="quick_links">
                <div class="q_title">                   
                </div>
                <div class="q_window">
                    <div class="q_top"></div>
                    <div class="q_main">

                        <h:inputTextarea value="#{EditorBean.value}" id="input"
                            style="width:100%; height:300px;">Sample FAQ</h:inputTextarea>

                        <h:outputScript>                        
                new TINY.editor.edit('editor',{
                    id:'input',
                    width:945,
                    height:175,
                    cssclass:'te',
                    controlclass:'tecontrol',
                    rowclass:'teheader',
                    dividerclass:'tedivider',
                    controls:['bold','italic','underline','strikethrough','|','subscript','superscript','|',
                              'orderedlist','unorderedlist','|','outdent','indent','|','leftalign',
                              'centeralign','rightalign','blockjustify','|','unformat','|','undo','redo','n',
                              'font','size','style','|','hr','link','unlink'],
                    footer:true,
                    fonts:['Verdana','Arial','Georgia','Trebuchet MS'],
                    xhtml:true,
                    cssfile:'style.css',
                    bodyid:'editor',
                    footerclass:'tefooter',
                    toggle:{text:'Source',activetext:'HTML',cssclass:'toggle'},
                    resize:{cssclass:'resize'}
                });
               </h:outputScript>

                    </div>
                    <div class="q_bottom"></div>
                </div>
                <h:commandButton value="Savebutton" action="#{EditorBean.test}"></h:commandButton>
            </div>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </h:form>
    </div>


</h:body>
</html>
```

If I remove the `<h:form>` tag, then only editor gets displayed, but the `<h:commandButton>` doesn't work.
If I keep the `<h:form>` tag, then the `<h:commandButton>` works, but the TinyEditor editor does not get initialized.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<h:outputScript>` works perfectly fine. The concrete problem is just in your own JavaScript code. You specified an ID of "input" in the TinyEditor configuration script:

```
id:'input',
```

However there is no such HTML element with that ID in the JSF-generated HTML output. Yes, you should be looking at the JSF-generated HTML output, because that's basically all what the browser is retrieving. JavaScript does not run in webserver, but in the webbrowser and sees the JSF-generated HTML output only. Rightclick page in browser and do *View Source* to see it yourself as well.

The generated ID of the `<h:inputTextarea>` has in this particular construct the ID of the `<h:form>` prepended. In your particular case, you didn't specify any ID for the `<h:form>`, so JSF will autogenerate one like so `j_id123` so that the HTML element ID of the `<textarea>` as generated by `<h:inputTextarea>` will become `j_id123:input`. You need to specify exactly that ID in the TinyEditor configuration script.

However, better is to specify a fixed ID on the `<h:form>`, as the autogenerated ID may change whenever you add/remove components to the view.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputTextarea id="input" />
    ...
```

This way the generated `<textarea>` will get an ID of `form:input`. Then you can just use it in the TinyEditor configuration script:

```
id:'form:input',
```

Comment: That explanation was very useful, Thanks! But its not working!!

Comment: If you have understood the explanation, then you would have elaborated "its not working" in more technical detail. But you didn't. So it's impossible to point out your mistake.

Comment: Sorry!!
I did the same What u said,

I have done following changes,
<br/>

<h:form id="form">
<h:inputTextarea id="input" value="#{EditorBean.value}"  
style="width:100%; height:300px;" >Sample FAQ</h:inputTextarea> 

id:'form:input'


So according to code, after entering text value ,getter n setter should be called which are in bean.
if i remove editor ,it works fine! but if i add editor, it wont!

As per your explanation, i feel that input text area is getting id of form:input but when i use it in TinyEditor script id:'form:input' ,it fails!

Comment: The concrete problem is still not clear. Does the textarea appear as editor or does it still appear unmodified?

Comment: Textarea is appearing as editor. I can do editor operation on that.

Comment: Okay, thus the problem as stated in your initial question is solved (you couldn't display/initialize the editor when it's enclosed in `<h:form>`). Your new problem is a completely different one. You should be asking a new question about this.